# Broken bubblesort program errors. UPDATED CODE

Tags: c, arrays, bubble-sort

So I am stuck on how to debug this program correctly and have it run. Can anyone shed some insight. It's suppose to sort an array or names then an array of ages.

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:24:22: warning: passing argument 1 of 'bubblesortname' from incompatible pointer type
       bubblesortname(fullname,age,SIZE);
                      ^
prog.c:9:8: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char (*)[25]'
       void bubblesortname(char *fullname[], int *age, int size);
```

Free cookies to anyone who can get this to run :) 
**

```
    #define SIZE 5
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdio.h>


    void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
    void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]);
    void bubblesortname(char fullname[][25], int *age, int size);
    void bubblesortage(char fullname[], int *age, int size);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
    {
        char fullname[SIZE][25];
        int age[SIZE];



        // promt user for names and ages
        input(fullname, age);
        //output unsorted names and ages
        output(fullname, age);

        bubblesortname(fullname,age,SIZE);

        output(fullname, age);

        //sorts age
        bubblesortage(fullname,age,SIZE);
        //
        output(fullname, age);


        return 0;
    }

    void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) 
        {
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter a full name\n");
            //scanf("%[\^n]\n", fullname[i]);
            fgets (fullname[i],40, stdin);
            printf("Enter the age\n");
            scanf("%d", &age[i]);

        }
    }

    void output(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            printf("%s, %d\n", fullname[i], age[i]);
    }//end function

    void bubblesortname(char fullname[][], int *age, int size)
    {
         int temp_age;
          char* temp_name;
          int j,i;

          for (i = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++i) 
          {
            for (j = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++j) 
            {
              if (strcmp(fullname[j], fullname[j + 1]) > 0) 
              {
                temp_age = age[i];
                age[j] = age[j + 1];
                age[j + 1] = temp_age;

                temp_name = fullname[j];
                fullname[j] = fullname[j + 1];
                fullname[j + 1] = temp_name;


                 }//end if

            }//end inner for

        }//end for

    }//end function

            bubblesortage(char fullname[][], int *age, int size) 
            {
                int j,i;
                int temp_age;
                char* temp_name;
                char temp[25];
                    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) 
                      {
                         for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) 
                            {
                                 if (age[j] > age[j + 1]) 
                                  {
                                    strcpy(temp, fullname[<index1>]);
                                    strcpy(fullname[index1], fullname[index2]);
                                    strcpy(fullname[index2], temp);
                                    temp_age = age[j];
                                    age[j] = age[j + 1];
                                    age[j + 1] = temp_age;
                                    temp_name = fullname[j];
                                    fullname[j] = fullname[j + 1];
                                    fullname[j + 1] = temp_name;

                                    }// end inner for

                            }// end outer for


                        }// end function
```

Comment: `void bubblesortname(char fullname[][25](or char (*fullname)[25]), int *age(or int age[]), int size);`

Comment: also `fgets (fullname[i],40, stdin);` : 40 is too large.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. What is the difference between the two?

Comment: `for (j = 0; i < SIZE - 1; ++j) ` : `i < SIZE - 1;` wrong.

Comment: lol yea the name has to have a max of 40...

Comment: `char *fullname[]` is meant array of `char*`, `char (*fullname)[25]` is meant pointer to  `char[25]`,

Comment: mmm my group partner wrote a bunch of stuff in c99 and it broke a bunch of stuff when i tried to convert it back.

Comment: So which one do I mean? array of *char right?

Comment: `char fullname[SIZE][25];` does not have a pointer.

Comment: I dont know what you guys are suggesting? I need to change everything to pointers?

Comment: you can write such as `input` and `output`.

Comment: I'm sorry write what as input and output?

Comment: `void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]);`

Comment: So I need to add Size to fullname?

Comment: you cannot write`char fullname[][]`. In general, the size of the array of can be omitted, only the leftmost dimension. program can not properly access if there is each size. E.g A[10][10], B[10][20], call(A),call(B) : How do you distinguish between doing?

Comment: Well the program doesn't work so I clearly don't understand... :(

Comment: @SaturdaycityEZ , Didn't you do what BLUEPIXY suggested? Doesn't the program work when you did that?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , Why don't you post an answer?

Comment: @CoolGuy One(`input`) is properly one(`bubblesortname`) bad. I thought that it can be easy to understand. and It has been determined that can not be understood. :-)

Comment: ah I just changed something

Comment: Like i know its bad... The error says it is.

Comment: also you can write like as `void bubblesortname(int rows, int cols, char fullname[rows][cols], int age[rows]);` in C99. `rows` instead of `size`. callerside `bubblesortname(SIZE, 25, fullname, age);`

Comment: C99 is bad. It wont compile in dev c++

Comment: So use `char fullname[][25]` or `char (*fullname)[25]`

Comment: If in the case correctly change, you need to change Of course `temp_name = fullname[j];`. Because they treated as a pointer(`char*`, but isn't). use such as `strcpy` instead of `=`.

Comment: I still get this prog.c:24:22: warning: passing argument 1 of 'bubblesortname' from incompatible pointer type
       bubblesortname(fullname,age,SIZE);

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is **Undefined Behavior** and is **never correct** `int c; while ((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);` is what you want to strip the `newline` left in the input buffer (or a better crafted  `scanf` format string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gimme my damn cookies `:)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 5

void input (char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void output (char fullname[][25], int age[]);
void bubblesortname (char fullname[][25], int *age, int size);
void bubblesortage (char fullname[][25], int *age, int size);
void fflush_stdin();

int main (void)
{
    char fullname[SIZE][25];
    int age[SIZE];

    // promt user for names and ages
    input (fullname, age);

    //output unsorted names and ages
    printf ("\n input provided:\n\n");
    output (fullname, age);

    // sorts by name
    bubblesortname (fullname, age, SIZE);

    printf ("\n sorted by name:\n\n");
    output (fullname, age);

    //sorts age
    bubblesortage (fullname, age, SIZE);

    printf ("\n sorted by age:\n\n");
    output (fullname, age);


    return 0;
}

void input (char fullname[][25], int age[])
{
    int i = 0;
    size_t nchr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf ("\nEnter a full name: ");
        if (fgets (fullname[i], 24, stdin) != NULL)
        {
            nchr = strlen (fullname[i]);
            while (nchr > 0 && (fullname[i][nchr -1] == '\n' || fullname[i][nchr -1] == '\r'))
                fullname[i][--nchr] = 0;
        }
        printf ("Enter the age    : ");
        scanf ("%d", &age[i]);
        fflush_stdin();
    }
}

void output (char fullname[][25], int age[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf (" %-30s, %d\n", fullname[i], age[i]);
}               //end function

void bubblesortname (char fullname[][25], int *age, int size)
{
    int j = 0, i = 0;
    int temp_age = 0;
    char temp_name[25] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        // for (j = 0; i < size - 1; ++j) {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; ++j) {
            if (strcmp (fullname[j], fullname[j + 1]) > 0) {
                temp_age = age[j + 1];
                age[j + 1] = age[j];
                age[j] = temp_age;

                strcpy (temp_name, fullname[j + 1]);
                strcpy (fullname[j + 1], fullname[j]);
                strcpy (fullname[j], temp_name);
            }           //end if
        }           //end inner for
    }               //end for
}               //end function

void bubblesortage (char fullname[][25], int *age, int size)
{
    int j = 0, i = 0;
    int temp_age = 0;
    char temp_name[25] = {0};

    for (i = 0; i < size - 1; ++i) {
        // for (j = 0; j < size - 1; ++j) {
        for (j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; ++j) {
            if (age[j] > age[j + 1]) {
                temp_age = age[j + 1];
                age[j + 1] = age[j];
                age[j] = temp_age;

                strcpy (temp_name, fullname[j + 1]);
                strcpy (fullname[j + 1], fullname[j]);
                strcpy (fullname[j], temp_name);
            }           // end inner for
        }           // end outer for
    }               // end function
}

void fflush_stdin()
{ int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); }
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/freecookies

Enter a full name: George Carver
Enter the age    : 143

Enter a full name: Albert Einstein
Enter the age    : 115

Enter a full name: Ma Ferguson
Enter the age    : 131

Enter a full name: George Charles Butte
Enter the age    : 116

Enter a full name: Alexander Hamilton
Enter the age    : 277

 input provided:

 George Carver                 , 143
 Albert Einstein               , 115
 Ma Ferguson                   , 131
 George Charles Butte          , 116
 Alexander Hamilton            , 277

 sorted by name:

 Albert Einstein               , 115
 Alexander Hamilton            , 277
 George Carver                 , 143
 George Charles Butte          , 116
 Ma Ferguson                   , 131

 sorted by age:

 Albert Einstein               , 115
 George Charles Butte          , 116
 Ma Ferguson                   , 131
 George Carver                 , 143
 Alexander Hamilton            , 277
```

Seriously, the issues you had were (1) your indexes on the bubble sorts were completely wrong, (2) you cannot assign strings to each other, you must copy string-to-string, and (3) `fflush(stdin)` is never correct resulting in **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: There's a nice cookie from me at least.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your program:

first, your function prototypes do not match your functions you provide later:

```
void input(char fullname[25], int age[]);
```

does not match

```
void input(char fullname[][25], int age[]) 

void output(char fullname[25], int age[]);
```

does not match

```
void output(char fullname[][25], int age[])

void bubblesortname(char *fullname[][25], int *age, int size);
```

does not match

```
void bubblesortname(char *fullname[], int *age, int size)
```

and finally

```
void bubblesortage(char *fullname[], int *age, int size);
```

and

```
bubblesortage(char *fullname[], int *ages, int size)
```

do not match either (note the missing return type that defaults to `int`).

You'll need to fix all of these to match.

Next, you need to decide on *what* you want to sort or - more specifically - what data you want to move if you recognise you have to swap two strings.

The way you have initially set up your data structures (one large 2-dimensional array) implies you want to sort the full-length individual strings instead of pointers to strings (which would be much more efficient since you would have to exchange only two pointers instead of 2 x 26 bytes).

A two-dimensional array is just a memory area of rows x columns x sizeof(element), so there are no pointers to swap, just data.

Alas, you decide and you decided for full strings.

For that to work you'll need a 26 byte (25 chars + trailing `'\0'`) temporary field within you `bubblesortname()` function:

```
char temp[25];
```

Once you found you need to swap two strings, do the following:

```
strcpy(temp, fullname[<index1>]);
strcpy(fullname[index1], fullname[index2]);
strcpy(fullname[index2], temp);
```

(don't forget to swap your age values as well to keep everything in sync).

Fix that yourself and you can keep your cookies ;)

Comment: Wait so which is the correct way to the fullname function?

Comment: Which is the correct way to list my fullname function?

Comment: you've got every information you need to fix your program. Just go ahead and do it.

Comment: char fullname[][25] vs char fullname[25] vs char *fullname[]? I am working on it but which is the proper full name declaration of this function?

Comment: char fullname[][25] is an array of 25-character strings.  You would use this if you wanted to pass a bunch of strings, and you knew the length of those strings and wanted the entire thing on the stack.  char fullname[25] is a single 25-character string.  You would use that if you wanted to pass a single string and you knew the length of the string and wanted it on the stack.  char *fullname[] is an array of pointers to characters.  You would use this if you wanted to pass a bunch of strings, but you didn't know or care about the length of those strings.